# PayPal Subscriptions: How to get Subscription details after payment?

Tags: paypal

I'm using the PayPal button to set a recurring payment plan, but I would love to get subscription details like user email and names when the user finishes paying. I have tried to use the code below to fetch details from PayPal, but I ended up with this error as shown after

var_dump => "object(stdClass)#1 (5) { ["name"]=> string(16) "VALIDATION_ERROR" ["debug_id"]=> string(12) "f1579954da9c" ["message"]=> string(29) "Invalid request. See details." ["information_link"]=> string(67) "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans#errors" ["details"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["field"]=> string(22) "template id is invalid" ["issue"]=> string(18) "Incorrect Plan Id." } } }"

CODE:
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/'.$plan_id);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.rawurlencode($token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
$response=json_decode($result);
var_dump($response);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: actually the main issue here was using the [deprecated  `v1/payments/billing-plans`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/v1/) API. Instead use the [`v1/billing/plans`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans) API for managing current Subscription plans -- although this question is more about Subscriptions themselves, not plans.

---

From the error, you are specifying an invalid plan_id; plan ids must begin with a "P-". Since your problem statement is to get the status of a user's actual *subscription* (not the plan), don't use a plan_id nor that API call.

A subscription id begins with "I-", and is returned in the onApprove data of a Subscription button, if you are using such a JS button. You can then use a Subscription id to [get the status](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_get) with an API call.

The most reliable way (since it does not depend on any client side code) for subscription ids to be populated within your backend is to create a webhook event listener to be notified of whenever [new Subscription events](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions) take place for that REST app/client_id . The most useful such event to listen to is `PAYMENT_SALE_COMPLETED` since this occurs every time a subscription is paid and can be used to mark it valid for 1 month (usual logic/business need), but there is also `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED` for when it begins.

For reconciliation, you can include an arbitrary `custom_id` when a subscription is created (within createSubscription if using the button, or the API create if using that). This `custom_id` will be returned in all webhooks related to that subscription, so you can determine which user/profile it is for.

Comment: Thank you @Preston PHX  for co-operation, here is the plan id i used while testing P-18E22255LU413640YMJITNOY

Comment: Right so that's used when creating a new subscription (the plan has the billing_cycles information), but is not used after a user subscribes.

Comment: Oh and you're calling the old "billing-plans" API, which is deprecated and not used for current Subscriptions. The current API is https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_get

Comment: Men! Thank you. I went through that API, and I have found the straightforward API to call, which gives back all the subscription details I wanted. Thank you for the co-operation. Here is the link https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_get